# Managed API for changing service paths

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a Windows Service installed on a machine.

In a new release, I've renamed the services .exe name (e.g., `MyService.exe` -> `Foo.Server.exe`).

I understand service executable paths can be changed by [modifying the registry](http://tech.chitgoks.com/2009/07/23/change-executable-path-of-windows-services/), but does a managed API exist so that I can be more confident it won't break in future releases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can PInvoke the SCM API, [ChangeServiceConfig](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681987%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and provide the lpBinaryPathName parameter.

Here is the PInvoke prototype from: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32/ChangeServiceConfig.html

```
[DllImport("Advapi32.dll", EntryPoint="ChangeServiceConfigW", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling=true, SetLastError=true)]
internal static extern bool ChangeServiceConfig(
    SafeHandle hService,
    int dwServiceType, 
    int dwStartType, 
    int dwErrorControl, 
    [In] string lpBinaryPathName,
    [In] string lpLoadOrderGroup, 
    IntPtr lpdwTagId,
    [In] string lpDependencies, 
    [In] string lpServiceStartName, 
    [In] string lpPassWord, 
    [In] string lpDisplayName
);
```

Using the [ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx) class to open the SCM and service you just call it like this:

```
static void ChangeServicePath(string svcName, string exePath)
{
    const int SERVICE_NO_CHANGE = -1;
    using (ServiceController control = new ServiceController(svcName))
        ChangeServiceConfig(control.ServiceHandle,
                            SERVICE_NO_CHANGE,
                            SERVICE_NO_CHANGE,
                            SERVICE_NO_CHANGE,
                            exePath,
                            null,
                            IntPtr.Zero,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null);
}
```

Comment: Note: Might want to use a "using" around control.ServiceHandle as it always returns a new copy. This way you rely on the GC to finalize the new copy.